# Where is the less.js compiled file after compiling?

Tags: javascript, css, less

Less - js side via script - should, in theory, compile the css and save it in a file.

example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="./style.less" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/3.9.0/less.min.js" data-async='true' data-env:'production' data-compress:'true'></script>
```

via php less leave the compiled file in js I have no idea where it is.
Where is the compiled file? does anyone know?

or: is there a method to let him put it directly somewhere?

thanks everybody.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you compile filename.less the compiled CSS code has been injected into the HTML DOM in a style tag with id less:filename.

To get the compilled CSS code you can also use:

```
less.pageLoadFinished.then(
    function() {
        console.log(document.getElementById('less:filename').innerHTML);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

From the suggestion of J.McLaren I evolved the thing in this:

```
if( document.querySelector('script[src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/3.9.0/less.min.js"]')||document.querySelector('script[src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/3.9.0/less.min.js"]') )
    {
        console.log("\n\n[⚠alert]: LessJs via simple script\n• If you are using lessjs via script remember to put data-async='true' or something will not work!\n::::  • Now you can copy the theme written by less in the head. Comment the Less script and load the compiled css parameters!\n• Remember that even if excellent, the script version is extremely slow!\n\n• We recommend using compilation via node js or php.\n::::     via php: shorturl.at/apy09\n::::     via node: shorturl.at/esSUY\n\n");

        let themecompiled = document.querySelector('style[id^="less:').innerHTML;
        alert("\n\n[⚠ alert]: LessJs Finished - you can copy the theme and deactivate less.js\n\n");
        prompt("Compiled code:", ""+themecompiled);

    }
```

In this way an alert will appear saying "Less has finished" and then a prompt where you can copy the compressed css.

Copy the css into a file, disable lessjs and it will be quick.

The system is also implemented on my [framework](https://github.com/ShapeGroup/kimera-frontend-framework)